# If $f(x) + 3x^2 = 2f(1-x)$ and $\lim _{x\to 1}f(x) =7$, find $\lim _{x\to 0} f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, functional-equations

> If $f(x) + 3x^2 = 2f(1-x)$ and $\lim _{x\to 1}f(x) =7$, find $\lim _{x\to 0} f(x)$.

I tried to solve this problem with this method:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)= \lim_{x\to 1}2f(1-x)-\lim_{x\to 1}3x^2$$

$$7= \lim _{x\to 1}2f(1-x) - 3 \Rightarrow 5=\lim_{x\to 1}f(1-x)$$

Putting $u=1-x $

$$\lim_{x\to 1}(1-x)=0$$

$$\lim_{u\to 0}f(u)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=5$$

Apperently this method is incorrect so could you point out the mistake for me? The correct answer is $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=14$.

Comment: As for your mistake: in the last line of your attempt, plugging u into the function will not necessarily give the same value as plugging x into it does, since $u = 1 - x$ which is not equal to $x$.

Comment: @sonicsid. In the line $\lim_{u\to 0}f(u)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=5$ both $u$ and $x$ are only dummy variables. The $\lim$ expressions are therefore equivalent.

Comment: @sonicsid. In both cases the argument of $f$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @md2perpe Got it now. Thank you. Apologies for causing confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Look like whoever give you the problem want you to take limit to $0$ directly:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) + \lim_{x\to 0} 3x^2 = \lim_{x\to 0} 2f(1-x).$$

Then you obtain $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) + 3\cdot 0 = 14$, thus the limit is $14$.

But they are not careful enough to see that your method also works. Or put it another way, there is no function $f$ that satisfies the property so that the limit at $0$ exists.

Following an idea from a (deleted) comment, we can find $f(x)$ explicitly (assuming only the functional equation, but not the limit at $1$). Put $x\mapsto 1-x$ in the equation, we have the system of equations

\begin{align}
f(x) + 3x^2 &=2f(1-x),\\
 f(1-x) + 3(1-x)^2 &= 2 f(x).
\end{align}

Solving for $f(x)$ gives

$$f(x)+3x^2 + 6(1-x)^2 = 4f(x),$$
thus $f(x) = x^2 + 2(1-x)^2$. It is clear that for this $f$, the limit at $x=1$ is not $7$.

Comment: so sonicsid's comment is incorrect?

Comment: Yes that comment is wrong. And the above answer is right.

Comment: @AndrewP. But their first comment (now deleted) is insightful (see the edit)

Comment: @ArcticChar After finding the function using that insight and seeing that the limit at x =1 was not to 7, it did not occur to me that such a function as stated in the question may not be possible at all and I thus thought it best to get rid of the comment altogether. Thank you for confirming my computation.